# Why does "divide calculator" generate the same value for all pixels?

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, modis

I would like to calculate the simple ratio (SR) using NDVI, SR=(1+NDVI)/(1-NDVI). And the result shows that all of the pixels have the same SR value. I checked the NDVI data is correct.

```
//Upload boundary of Inner Mongolia
var IM = ee.FeatureCollection("users/zhaiyg_GEE/IM_boundary");

//Get MOD13A1
var MODIS_VI = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1')
                 .filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-12-31')
                 .map(function(image) {return image.clip(IM);});
var NDVI = MODIS_VI.select('NDVI');

//Select the first date to test
var img=NDVI.first();
//To check the NDVI values, looks correct.
var NDVI_test = img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.percentile([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]),IM,500);
print(NDVI_test);
//Calculate SR. 10000 is scale factor.
var test = (img.multiply(0.0001)).divide(img.multiply(-0.0001).add(1));
//Check the SR results that all the pixels have the same value. 
var perc_1 = test.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.percentile([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]),IM,500);
print(perc_1);
```

The console shows this:

[image]

I am really confused. I test step by step, and find that the problem is "divide calculator". Why does the "divide calculator" generate the same value for all pixels? Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percentiles are computed using histograms, and outliers can cause the histogram buckets to be coarser than expected.  In this case, there are valuers near 10000, that when you multiply them by -0.0001 and add 1, become nearly 0, so you're dividing by nearly zero, creating a very large value, and thus, causing the histogram buckets to be large.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/08ed11365351bc7f0f36837439702cfd

You can either specify a large number for maxBuckets to the percentiles reducer or filter out the outliers.

Comment: You are right. Some outliers bring this issue. Now it works. Thank you very much.